# Ender 3 first layer of ESD PLA printing on raft fails

Tags: print-quality, pla, rafts

I was asked to print something with ESD PLA and the first layer, on a raft, is coming out like this:

[image: Badly printed ESD PLA first layer on raft]

Nozzle temperature was 220 °C and I'm using the default Cura draft profile.

Can you provide any tips on how to get a good print with this?

Comment: Can you also add your speed settings?

Comment: Do you have the rest of the print specs? Like, when does the fan come on (if at all); what is the extrusion speed; what is the print head speed; what is the bed temp; what is your extrusion multiplier set at;  (anything else which might be pertinent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gap between the raft and the first layer is too large (you need to switch to expert mode in Ultimaker Cura to see the values of the option before you can change them) and the hotend is too hot (normal PLA generally prints at 190 °C, ESD PLA prints at higher temperatures; you could aim for 210 °C as a start), This makes it difficult to precisely deposition the first layer on the raft as the nozzle drags the hot filament causing inaccurate first layer deposition.

Furthermore, PLA generally doesn't require a raft to print the part. The Creality Ender 3 has a rough bed (like a BuildTak surface), you could print directly onto the bed surface.

[Source](https://www.3dxtech.com/3dxstat-esd-pla-3d-printing-filament/) states:

> Extruder Temp:  Typically 210-220°C.  ESD PLA is a filled product and
>   has a higher melt viscosity vs. unfilled PLA.  Therefore, it is
>   sometimes necessary to print at higher temperatures than your standard
>   PLA to allow the resin to flow properly.

This implies that a hotend of 220 °C mot not be hot enough, in that case the filament is too cold and viscous and gets dragged because the gap is too large.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions but I have no issue with regular Pla. This is special electrostatic discharge filament and was wondering if it requires something different. Cheers

Comment: PLA is _usually_ 185 to 205C. YMMV

Comment: @Huskey27 I've made changes to my answer, you might be printing at a too low temperature. Filament dragging is frequently seen when filament is too hot, but apparently for ESD PLA it can happen when it is too cold to.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, all was going well last night so I went to bed while it was printing with a brim to keep it from lifting. Temp was about 220 but then [this](https://imgur.com/a/JAE4N7D) happened.  

The layer lifted right off the body and ended in a mess :/

Comment: @Huskey27 That is a new question